# Two "just now" time bars when going back to feed in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

This is what I did to find the bug:

1. I opened the app.
2. It automatically opened to the feed, and started loading new feed messages.
3. I saw a feed thing that I was interested in, so I tapped it (while new feed messages were still loading).
4. I read the thing I tapped on, and then tapped the back button.
5. The feed was still loading (apparently it pauses when you leave the feed), but I saw this:

> [image: two "Just now"!]

Could this be unborked? I'm using a Galaxy S4 with Android 4.3.

Comment: Cannot be repro'd on v1.0.83: opening the app doesn't automatically load new feed message (could be only me, though), pull-to-refresh library has been changed to Android's native feature without adding a new entry, and HNQ on the top prevent the time bar showing on the top (although maybe irrelevant)...